# Django websocket channels how to server push while Channels Group is not empty

Tags: django, websocket, subscription, django-channels

I have following scenario using django and channels, a client connects via Websocket and wants to subscribe some country news. So internally his subscription request will start a function with a infinite loop sending the country news to the channels group (while the group is not empty). My question is should this infinite loop run in separately thread? Should I use threading module and start a new thread?

Thank you.

Comment: read python asyncio (Asynchronous I/O, event loop, coroutines and tasks) documentation I hope this could help you

Comment: @hadi thank you for the advice.
I saw some videos about python asyncio. And now noted that django channels is already async so there was nothing to worry.

I wonder how can I know if the async infinite loop is still active or not?
Since the infinite loop only starts when at least one client subscribe the coutnry news. I would like to avoid starting 2 infinite loops for the same news. Do you know maybe how to deal with it in django, since global variables should be avoided.